# Request Yahoo Web Service With IP Not Domain

Tags: web-services, dns

i am trying to access yahoo exchange currency web service with IP instead of domain name an the following error message is returned  :
"The service's server DNS address could not be found."
When access URL with domain name it returns data as following :
http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote
When try to access it with IP it returns the above message :
[http:// 208.71.44.31/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote](http://%20208.71.44.31/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote)
regards.

Comment: cause security team need to add role to allow this request,i neet to give them ip and port not domain

Comment: Usually big companies like yahoo have thousands of servers and they use load ballancing. So the resolbed ip adress isnt really stable.

Comment: http://208.71.44.31/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote works like a charm...